# Дамп БД кликом по кнопке

Tags: php

Написал дамп БД в csv файл, путем клика по кнопке.

```
<?php

    if( isset( $_POST['dump'] ) )
    {

mysqli_select_db($mysqli,$database)
or die ('error ' . mysqli_error());



header('Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=dump.csv');

$output = fopen('php://output', 'w');


fputcsv($output, array('1 stolbec', '2 stolbec', '3 stolbec', '4 stolbec'));
$results = mysqli_query($mysqli,'SELECT * FROM user');


while ($results1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) :

fputcsv($output, $results1);

endwhile;

    }
?>


<form method="POST">
    <input type="submit" name="dump" value="dump" />
</form>
```

Как сделать так, чтобы все структура была такая же как и БД? ну т.е вся информация распределена по столбцам.

Comment: А с этим кодом что не так?

Comment: @u_mulder сейчас вся информация находится в 1ом столбце

Comment: Что за информация, в каком она столбце, а сами разбирайтесь, вы ведь тут все телепаты.